# how to setup a javascript namespace

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript. I have a script that contains various classes which I want to wrap inside a namespace.

After some reading I tried the below, however I get an error, "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Foo'. What am I doing wrong?

```
var monitor = {

class Foo{
    constructor(element_id, options){
        // some code
    }

    init = () => {
        some code
    }

    some_function = (data) => {
        // some code
    }


   }

 class Bar{
     // some code
  }

 }
```

Comment: When writing new code, you should use ES modules: `export class Foo { … } export class Bar { … }`, no `monitor` (or at best `import * as monitor from '…'` in another module).

Comment: 1. This is not a *namespace* as that doesn't exist in JS. This is a plain JS object which is supposed to contain keys and values. 2. `class` is not valid inside JS object initialiser syntax. 3. Even if it could be made valid, this might be [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) as the idiomatic way to solve the core problem is to use modules. Then you can separate what is where via the module system.

Comment: Wouldn't there be some code there without the //? Then it would be a syntax error, right? And you forgot to export your class using ES modules.

init = () => {
        // some code
    }

Comment: …but if for some reason you really need namespace objects, either use the *revealing module pattern* or a simple object literal. In either case, it's `class Foo {…} class Bar { …} var monitor = { Foo, Bar }` or `var monitor: { Foo: class { … }, Bar: class { … } };`

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have *namespaces* as such. As Bergi said, the modern way to handle not making everything global is to use [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules). (Prior to that, we used to fake it by creating objects with function [and other] properties on them, but it was a workaround and no longer necessary.) Re your specific question: The problem with the code is you're trying to declare a class inside an object literal, which simply isn't valid syntax.

Comment: ```var monitor = {
  Foo: class {
    constructor(element_id, options) {
      // Constructor code
    }

    init() {
      // Initialization code
    }

    some_function(data) {
      // Function code
    }
  },

  Bar: class {
    constructor() {
      // Constructor code for Bar
    }

    // Other methods and properties for Bar
  }
};
const fooInstance = new monitor.Foo("elementId", { option: "value" });
fooInstance.init();```

try using this way

Comment: it can be achieved via module pattern

Comment: Can you please give us the links to the articles you read? It appears that they contain misleading information.

Comment: @MisterJojo — While DOM has namespaces, and the DOM API (including the JS implementation of it) has features to access them, that clearly isn't what this question is asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"namespace" isn't a term that is generally used in JavaScript.

Historically, it was sometimes used to mean "Using an object (with many properties) assigned to a single global variable instead of using many global variables".

The general syntax for creating an object is:

```
{
    property_name: value,
    second_property_name: value
}
```

There are *some* shorthand syntaxes that can be used in object literals, but none of them are for creating a class.

You need to be explicit about the property name and use a [class expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class).

For example:

```js
var monitor = {
    Foo: class {
        constructor() {
            // etc
        }
    }  
}
```

**However** - it is 2023 and we have had half a decade of good browser support for [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules), a tool **designed** to do that organisation rather than the old hack that was "namespaces".

So don't do that. Use modules instead.

*monitor.js*

```js
export class Foo {
    constructor(element_id, options) {
        // some code
    }
    init = () => {
        some code
    }
    some_function = (data) => {
        // some code
    }
}

export class Bar {
    // some code
}
```

*main.js*

```js
import * as monitor from "./monitor.js";

const foo = new monitor.Foo();
```

Comment: thanks very much! I shouldn't have googled namespace